# Rails - Routing using custom param in Permalink

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have Products page that use the ugly param to handle sorting.

```
products_path(sort: "asc")

# resulting in
/products?sort=asc
```

I'm trying to make the URL looks like `/products/asc`. So I'm playing with the **routes**:

```
# routes.rb
get "/products/:sort", to: "products#index", as: "products_path"
```

Now, going to `/products/asc` works perfectly fine.

But `products_path(sort: "asc")` still generate `/products?sort=asc`.

Is there a way to make it generate the pretty URL?

Thanks

**[EDIT and ANSWER]**

I typo the `as:`. Should be:

```
# routes.rb
get "/products/:sort", to: "products#index", as: "products"
```

Answer (score 1):

Move `get "/products/:sort", to: "products#index", as: "products"` above `resources :projects` in routes.rb

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Actually I made mistake, it supposed to be `as: "products"` instead of `as: "products_path"`

Answer (score 0):

I typo the as:. Should be:

```
# routes.rb
get "/products/:sort", to: "products#index", as: "products"
```